# +1 keyboard shortcut for google+?

Tags: google-plus

Is there any way of adding custom keyboard shortcuts to a specific page? In this case, I would like Google+ to behave a little bit like Google Reader, and use the shortcut 'v' to open the link in a Google+ post in a new browser tab. I would also like to be able to '+1' a post with a key press.

Comment: You want to do this just for you? Then it might be helpful to write a Greasemonkey script which does so. But I don't know how that could be done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google's [+ button policy](http://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/webmasters/+1/button/policy.html),

> Publishers may not alter or obfuscate a Google+ Button, [...]

This means you are probably not allowed to do what you want. If you want to do it anyway, you should ask Google first, they may authorize you to use the keyboard shortcut and might provide you a URL to do that (only if they are okay with that, of course).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Chrome this my be useful:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nafbdgpajdhkjnaeafkboodleapnpjbg?hl=en-US